# How to integrate flash player into GeckoFX without xulrunner

Tags: c#, flash, geckofx

I am using C# Forms application that integrates GeckoFX browser to access web page. The web page is designed to use Flash.

I was able to integrate Flash driver into older version of GeckoFX (33.0) that is using xulrunner. The flash driver (NPSWF32.dll) is simply put into xulrunner\plugins directory and everything works fine.

However, I am not able to get the project run with recent versions of GeckoFX (eg. 45.x) that is not based on xulrunner. Is there any idea where should I put NPSWF32.dll?

Comment: Flash has gone the way of the dino

Comment: I have successfully enabled flash in v45 but not v60. In a folder, I have the executable of my app and a folder named Firefox that contains the geckofx distribution files. Inside this Firefox folder, I created a folder named plugins and copied NPSWF32.dll. In my app I have Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox"); and I can use flash.

Comment: Great, it worked for me, v45! Thx